# How to set up SSH keys for Jenkins Blue Ocean using Kubernetes and Helm

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-blueocean

I have a CI system set up using the [stable Jenkins Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins) with the BlueOcean plugin.

In my SCM system (BitBucket Server), I have a Jenkins build user created with SSH keys configured.

What I'd like to do is bootstrap the Jenkins install with the SSH key so that when configuring a BlueOcean pipeline, authentication is handled seamlessly.  As it is, I have to go in to the repository I want to build and add access for the SSH key generated by BlueOcean.  This is obviously not ideal as it adds an additional manual step for *each* build pipeline to be configured.

The Jenkins Helm chart documentation specifies an `Agent.volumes` value in `values.yaml` that can be used to mount, for instance, a Kubernetes secret containing the SSH keys.  However, this is *agent* configuration, so presumably would allow for SCM authentication from a build agent (e.g., from a Jenkinsfile).  What I want to do is bootstrap the keys into Jenkins *master*.

I see that there is a `Master.CredentialsXmlSecret` which allows for a Kubernetes secret containing a Credentials XML file, but the documentation on this is sparse (or non-existent).

Has anyone set up Jenkins on Kubernetes/Helm with this kind of SSH configuration?

*Edit: So I have managed to produce a correct `credentials.xml` file by logging in to Jenkins and manually setting up the SSH keys, then copying the produced `credentials.xml` file, running it through `base64` encoding, adding it as a Kubernetes secret and then binding it to `Master.CredentialsXmlSecret` in the Jenkins Helm chart's `values.yaml`.  After doing that, my Jenkins instance loads up with the `credentials.xml` file in place (`/var/jenkins_home/credentials.xml`).  The Credentials don't appear to be loading into the Jenkins UI correctly but I think I'm on the right track.

Comment: The path I'm going down (still in progress) is starting up the Jenkins instance, manually configuring SSH credentials in the UI, then copying the `/var/jenkins_home/credentials.xml` file, running it through `base64` encoding, storing it as a Kubernetes secret, and then mounting that secret to the `Master.CredentialsXmlSecret` property in `values.yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably set it up with an API call to bitbucket to set up the SSH key. Something like this with API 1.0

```
$ curl --user <USER>:<PASSWORD> -X POST \
  https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/users/<USER>/ssh-keys \
  --data-urlencode "key=<PUBLIC_KEY>" \
  --data-urlencode "label=<LABEL>"
```

Documented [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/ssh-keys-resource-296911735.html), or API 2.0:

```
 $ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d '{"key": "ssh-ed25519 ...."}' \
   https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/<USER</ssh-keys
```

Documented [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/users/%7Busername%7D/ssh-keys)

Not sure what type of permissions you are looking for but you may want [a repo SSH key pair](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pipelines_config/ssh/key_pair) for Jenkins Blue Ocean pipelines.

In either case, you will have to build your custom docker image with an [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) script that picks up the ssh key generated and posts it wherever you want to post it.